# sql query ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have table data like below.

```
    d1  date                        sale_time
    N   2012-03-09 00:00:00.000     TBD
    No  2011-09-26 00:00:00.000     2:00 PM CT
    N   2012-01-26 00:00:00.000     1:00 PM CT
    N   2012-03-07 00:00:00.000     1:00 PM ET
    yes 2012-02-23 00:00:00.000     Accepting Offers
```

I want the result order by date asc,sale time asc (if sale time is not contain time it should come last records)
i want out put like

```
 d1     date                            sale_time
    No  2011-09-26 00:00:00.000     2:00 PM CT
    N   2012-01-26 00:00:00.000     1:00 PM CT       
    N   2012-03-07 00:00:00.000     1:00 PM ET
    YEs 2012-02-23 00:00:00.000     Accepting Offers
    N   2012-03-09 00:00:00.000     TBD
```

i have tried with below query but getting error while converting sale time to date.

```
select 
  * 
from 
  table 
order by  
  date asc,
  convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(replace(sale_time,' ',''), 
  1, 
  (CHARINDEX(':',replace(sale_time,' ',''))+4))) asc
```

Comment: "If sale time is not contain a time  ...  error while converting sale time to date"

Comment: I have data like that in my table ,I need output like that

Comment: Someone deleted my comment? OK; where do those go, and do we get a reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

First some test data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(d1 VARCHAR(100),[date] DATETIME,sale_time VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
    ('N','2012-03-09 00:00:00.000','TBD'),
    ('No','2011-09-26 00:00:00.000','2:00 PM CT'),
    ('N','2012-01-26 00:00:00.000','1:00 PM CT'),
    ('N','2012-03-07 00:00:00.000','1:00 PM ET'),
    ('yes','2012-02-23 00:00:00.000','Accepting Offers')
```

Then the query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        (
            CASE 
                WHEN NOT CHARINDEX(':',sale_time)=0
                THEN SUBSTRING(sale_time,0,5)
                ELSE NULL
            END
        ) AS sale_time_format,
        tbl.d1,
        tbl.date,
        tbl.sale_time
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT
    CTE.d1,
    CTE.date,
    CTE.sale_time
FROM
    CTE 
ORDER BY
    CTE.sale_time_format DESC,
    CTE.date
```

You don't accualy need to order by date as well. Just the sale_time_format to get the result you want. I have include it because you might have more data.